# Rename EKCalendar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

How do I change the name of a calendar? I have:

```
EKCalendar *cal;

cal=[store calendarWithIdentifier:@"5F9A5BE0-03A9-4FE8-BD1E-2647F39E268F"];    

cal.title = @"Calendar custom 2";
cal.source = localSource;
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL saved = [store saveCalendar:cal commit:YES error:&error];
NSLog(@"%d -> %@",saved,error);
```

But this doesn't save, this print:

```
0 -> Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=15 "That calendar may not be moved to another account." UserInfo=0xb05c8a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=That calendar may not be moved to another account.}
```

Someone could help me!!

Comment: why do you change a source?

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation `source` can't be changed, try changing `title` property only.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem. The issue is that, you should not be setting the source for existing calendar. EKSource should only be set while creating new calendar.